# How do i run another class on hover in css

Tags: css

I know that you can do something like this in scss.

```
.projectItem:hover{
    .subNavigator{
        display: grid;
    }
}
```

is there a way to do this in css?

Comment: Can you please explain with full details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
.projectItem:hover .subNavigator{
    display: grid;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this:

```css
.parent {
  height: 150px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: red;
}

.subNavigator {
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.parent:hover .subNavigator {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="subNavigator">
  </div>
</div>
```